# Why did my withdrawal from EtherDelta fail?

Tags: tokens, bad-jump, etherdelta

I have 10 VERI coins on EtherDelta. I tried to transfer them to my wallet so I can then make my next move to transfer them to somewhere else. Over 4 hours has passed and these tokens have not moved with a warning of a bad jump destination. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x818345b40e95433f6c98e2f7ac3c11d51900dbd6c1ce61a7ec1f9e42053a6865

Comment: The error indicates the transaction has failed, ie it is like it never happened. You should ask to Ether Delta support for help to credit back your tokens, or to retry the operation with another transaction.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have just under 10 coins, and tried to withdraw 11. Try withdrawing ~9.9999 instead.

### Approach

"Bad Jump" usually means that the method called `throw;` at some point, so let's try to find it.

From your Etherscan link, click the contract address, and then the [Contract Source] tab. Find the withdrawToken() method that the etherscan transaction page says you called:

```
function withdrawToken(address token, uint amount) {
    if (token==0) throw;
    if (tokens[token][msg.sender] < amount) throw;
    ...
}
```

`token` was set to `0x8f3470a7388c05ee4e7af3d01d8c722b0ff52374`, so the first `throw` isn't the problem.

The next line checks how many tokens you own to make sure you don't withdraw more than that. Let's find out how many you own.

`msg.sender` was `0x253b8771fd0b2d6f4e7db5aaaee0ede207cb31ab` in the transaction you shared. We can look up the balance with that info in the [MyEtherWallet Contracts tab](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts).

Copy in the contract address from the Etherscan transaction page. Copy in the ABI from the Etherscan [Contract Source] tab. Copy in the token address from the first argument at the bottom of the Etherscan txn page. Copy in the owner address from the "From" field in the Etherscan txn page. Click the [Read] button. It should look like:

[image: MEW Etherdelta lookup]

The hex value of that balance is (in `ipython`):

```
In [1]: hex(9999925439648120384)
Out[1]: '0x8ac6df349a9e3e40'
```

Your original transaction requested a balance of `0x98a7d9b8314c0000` which is larger than the token balance. That would cause a `throw` and the withdrawal to fail. Depending on how you input the withdrawal, you can try withdrawing your full amount as: `9999925439648120384`, `9.999925439648120384`, or `0x8ac6df349a9e3e40`.