# Continuosly receiving Bad Jump error

Tags: bad-jump

I am continuously receiving "Bad Jump" Error. I followed a guide found here:
[Why did my withdrawal from EtherDelta fail?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24509/why-did-my-withdrawal-from-etherdelta-fail/24517)

and have figured out my token value for deposit and withdraw is set to 0. Here is the transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x77224b7b7b71326e8bbcbb5fdcd4dc6d9daabc0729a8eb05c1b24e61bc11df1b

I need to change the deposit and withdraw amount to do my entire balance if desired. Will pay .5 ETH to first person that resolves this issue for me step by step.

Comment: Just noticed but you're not getting a `Bad Jump` error, it says `Bad instruction`..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your transaction and other transaction from your address to Etherdelta contract, you are trying to deposit more units of tokens that what you really have, hence the BAD JUMP (exception).

Comment: I am trying to only deposit half of the tokens I actually have into my Ether delta. There is a restriction on my deposit/withdraw amount which I am trying to increase. Anyone that can increase my deposit/withdraw amount to my entire token total balance I'll send the .5 ETH too.

Answer (score 0):

A clue maybe this comment on the `depositToken()` function.

```
function depositToken(address token, uint amount) {
//remember to call Token(address).approve(this, amount) or this contract will not be able to do the transfer on your behalf.
if (token==0) throw;
if (!Token(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, this, amount)) throw;
tokens[token][msg.sender] = safeAdd(tokens[token][msg.sender], amount);
Deposit(token, msg.sender, amount, tokens[token][msg.sender]);
```

}

//remember to call Token(address).approve(this, amount) or this contract will not be able to do the transfer on your behalf.

So try that `approve()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am not a programer so I may need you to walk me through how to edit and execute the changes. You'll be rewarded if successful :)

Answer (score 0):

You should give EtherDelta the right to do the transfer on your behalf.

Precise answer depends on which wallet you are using. I'm going to explain the solution for MyEtherWallet. First of all go to [MEW Contract Lab](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts). After that input the address of the contract which tokens you would like to trade with EtherDelta to **Contract Address**. According to the transaction you've sent it is InternetNodeToken:

> 0x0b76544f6c413a555f309bf76260d1e02377c02a

Then go to code [page of that contract in Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0b76544f6c413a555f309bf76260d1e02377c02a#code) and copy **Contract ABI**. Paste it in **ABI / JSON Interface**.

The next step is to choose **approve** in drop-down list.

After that copy EtherDelta Contract address from your [previous transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x77224b7b7b71326e8bbcbb5fdcd4dc6d9daabc0729a8eb05c1b24e61bc11df1b)

> 0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819

and paste it as **spender address**

The last step is to fill in the amount of InternetNodeToken which you'd like to let EtherDelta to manage. If it is all (100224.444844) you should type

> 0x1755d7a9ac

which is 100224.444844 * 10^6 as hexadecimal.

After that just follow the instructions of MyEtherWallet.

Comment: All is well except I don't see "Approve" as an option on the drop down after I've selected "Access".

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure that you've copied all the ABI field (there is a button to copy it fully to clipboard)? It starts with _[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newSellPrice","type":"uint256"},_ and ends with _,"name":"Burn","type":"event"}]_. **approve** is the third option in drop down.

Comment: Yup I used the copy button on the ABI field. Some strange stuff.. The maximum I would like to be able to deposit/withdraw should be 140k as well.. I have more in another account which is having the same issues.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is possible to approve more than you have. You may perform the same steps for your second ethereum account

Comment: Which thats fine but it won't let me approve them so how to I deposit into Ether Delta from MEW? Thats really what I'm looking for because I keep getting the failed transactions as you can see on MEW.

Comment: It is also possible just to send the raw transaction to InternetNodeToken but MyEtherWallet is much more easier to understand for non-programmer, IMHO

Comment: First of all, we should give EtherDelta the right to do the transfer on your behalf. After that you may just repeat your [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x77224b7b7b71326e8bbcbb5fdcd4dc6d9daabc0729a8eb05c1b24e61bc11df1b) the way you did it before. Steps described in my answer are aimed on "increase of your deposit/withdraw amount".